# What are the parts of speech for as, so, such?

Tags: parts-of-speech

> When thus gentle, Bessie seemed to me the best, prettiest, kindest being in the world; and I wished most intensely that she would always be so pleasant and amiable, and never push me about, or scold, or task me unreasonably, **as** she was too often wont to do.  Bessie Lee must, I think, have been a girl of good natural capacity, for she was smart in all she did, and had a remarkable knack of narrative; **so**, at least, I judge from the impression made on me by her nursery tales.  She was pretty too, if my recollections of her face and person are correct.  I remember her as a slim young woman, with black hair, dark eyes, very nice features, and good, clear complexion; but she had a capricious and hasty temper, and indifferent ideas of principle or justice: still, **such as** she was, I preferred her to anyone else at Gateshead Hall.
>   (Jane Eyre)

Is *as* a pronoun and object of *do*?
Is *so* an adverb (complement of *judge*)?
Is *such* a pronoun, and *as* a conjunctive?

Comment: I don't understand why at the end of, in each of your question, you use `**` marks? What does it signify?

Comment: I intended to separate excerpts from my question sentences.

Comment: There is no need to separate the questions from the quote: They are rendered differently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*As* is a subordinator meaning ‘in the manner or way that’. *So* is an adverb, meaning ‘of that nature or description; of or in that condition’. *Such* is an adjective meaning ‘having the character that he (it) has, no more and no less; used chiefly with a depreciatory or contemptuous reference, or apologetically.’ (All definitions from the OED.)

(*Parts of speech* is less used than it once was. The preferred, and more accurate, term is *word class*. It is usual to separate word classes into lexical words and function words. The ‘Student Grammar of Spoken and Written English’ identifies as lexical words nouns, lexical verbs, adjectives and adverbs. It identifies function words as determiners, pronouns, auxiliary verbs, prepositions, adverbial particles, coordinators and subordinators.)